# How to extract var (values) from <script> of html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i am currently using

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('www.randomwebsite.com').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
details= soup.find('script')
```

this is returning me the following script.

```
     <script>
var Url = "https://www.example.com";
                if(Url != ''){code}
 else {code
}
  </script>
```

i want to have the output as following.
**https://www.example.com**

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

text = """
     <script>
var Url = "https://www.example.com";
                if(Url != ''){code}
 else {code
}
  </script>
"""


match = re.search('Url = "(.*?)"', text)

print(match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com
```

Comment: Tried this but no luck. returning with none

Comment: https://tracking.earnkaro.com/visitretailer/508?id=103894&shareid=ENKR2020090345700421&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB08645RXJ6%2Fref%3Dox_sc_act_title_1%3Fsmid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26psc%3D1

i need the var which comes in script as cashbackUrl

Comment: Yup please use my code in question to get the script. this link redirects to amazon. i need the final link but when i run the code it doesnot redirect. it returns with a html of java script
my goal is to get final link of amazon

Answer (score 0):

To print the `cashback_url`, you can try this script:

```
import re
import requests


url = 'https://tracking.earnkaro.com/visitretailer/508?id=103894&shareid=ENKR2020090345700421&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB08645RXJ6%2Fref%3Dox_sc_act_title_1%3Fsmid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26psc%3D1'
html_data = requests.get(url).text

cashback_url = re.search(r'var cashbackUrl = "(.*?)"', html_data).group(1)

print(cashback_url)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08645RXJ6/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=AT95IG9ONZD7S&psc=1&ck&tag=EK003221-21
```