# How to get the final url for a short link using python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, response

I have the following urls:

- Short url: `https://ekaro.in/enkr2020090345700421`
- 1st redirect: `https://tracking.earnkaro.com/visitretailer/508?id=103894&shareid=ENKR2020090345700421&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB08645RXJ6%2Fref%3Dox_sc_act_title_1%3Fsmid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26psc%3D1`
- Destination url: `https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08645RXJ6/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=AT95IG9ONZD7S&psc=1&ck&tag=EK003221-21`

This is the code I used to get to 1st redirect:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://ekaro.in/enkr2020090345700421'

source = requests.get(url).text
print(source)
```

This returns the following html document:

```
url: https://tracking.earnkaro.com/visitretailer/508?id=103894&shareid=ENKR2020090345700421&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB08645RXJ6%2Fref%3Dox_sc_act_title_1%3Fsmid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26psc%3D1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
                    <meta property="og:title" content="Amazon Store" />
            <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
            <meta property="og:image" content="https://asset20.ckassets.com/resources/image/stores/amazon.png" />
                
                    <script>
                var cashbackUrl = "https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08645RXJ6/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=AT95IG9ONZD7S&psc=1&ck&tag=EK003221-21";
                if(cashbackUrl != ''){
                    var dataLayer = [{
                        'event': 'exitclick',
                        'customerId': '103894',
                        'storeName': "Amazon Store",
                        'exitID': 'ENKR20200905A14248334',
                        'eventCallback': function() {
                            window.location = cashbackUrl
                        }
                    }];
                } else {
                    var dataLayer = [{
                        'event': 'exitclick',
                        'customerId': '103894',
                        'storeName': "Amazon Store",
                        'exitID': 'ENKR20200905A14248334'
                    }];
                }
            </script>
                
            <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
            <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-MDR24WQ');</script>
            <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
        
    
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MDR24WQ"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    
</body>
</html>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The destination url I need is in:

```
<script> 
var cashbackUrl = .......
</script>
```

How to extract `var cashbackUrl`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract var (values) from <script> of html using beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63753039/how-to-extract-var-values-from-script-of-html-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import re

url=requests.get('https://tracking.earnkaro.com/visitretailer/508?id=103894&shareid=ENKR2020090345700421&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.in%2Fgp%2Fproduct%2FB08645RXJ6%2Fref%3Dox_sc_act_title_1%3Fsmid%3DAT95IG9ONZD7S%26psc%3D1').text
amz_link = re.findall(r'cashbackUrl = .*;', url)
print(amz_link[0].replace('cashbackUrl =', '').replace('"', '').replace(';', '').strip())
```

is the working code i took a help from

[Getting javascript variable value while scraping with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283742/getting-javascript-variable-value-while-scraping-with-python)

thanks to [Kamikaze_goldfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6042206/kamikaze-goldfish) for the answer and also to [F M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9509783/f-m) for his support and [αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658985/%CE%B1%D4%8B%C9%B1%D2%BD%D4%83-%CE%B1%D0%BC%D1%94%D1%8F%CE%B9c%CE%B1%CE%B7) for his spontaneous reply.

the solution is

```
amz_link = re.findall(r'cashbackUrl = .*;', url)
print(amz_link[0].replace('cashbackUrl =', '').replace('"', '').replace(';', '').strip())
```